# Get all users based on a specific permission/role in .Net CSOM in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, client-object-model

I want to get the list of all the users who have a particular role/permission on a site.

For example, I need the list of users who have edit rights `RoleType=Editor` using **.Net CSOM** in SharePoint 2013. They can be in any group. I tried many things. However, it seems there isn't a straight forward way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize [Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getusereffectivepermissions(v=office.15).aspx) to gets the effective permissions that the specified user has within the web site.

**Example 1: Getting users by permission**

The first example demonstrates how to retrieve users by **permission**, in particular users who *can edit list items* (using [PermissionKind.EditListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.permissionkind%28v=office.15%29.aspx)):

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
      //Retrieve site users             
      var users = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Web.SiteUsers.Where(u => u.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User));
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      //Retrieve users permissions
      var userPermissionsResults = users.ToDictionary(user => user, user => ctx.Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions(user.LoginName));
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      //Filter the users who can edit list items      
      var usersCanEditListItems = new List<User>();
      foreach (var result in userPermissionsResults)
      {
          var user = result.Key;
          var userPermissions = result.Value.Value;
          if (userPermissions.Has(PermissionKind.EditListItems))
          {
             usersCanEditListItems.Add(user);
          }
      }
 }
```

**Example 2: getting users by role**

In case of **role type or permission levels** the example become a little more complicated since  we need to:

- retrieve the list of permissions for a role type (step 1 and 2)
- get users with permissions (step 3 and 4)
- filter users by role permissions (step 5)

Example:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     //1.Retrieve role definition 
     var roleDef = ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Editor);
     ctx.Load(roleDef);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     //2.Get permission levels for role 
     var permLevelNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof (PermissionKind));
     var permissionLevels = permLevelNames.Select(permLevelName => (PermissionKind) Enum.Parse(typeof (PermissionKind), permLevelName)).Where(permissionLevel => roleDef.BasePermissions.Has(permissionLevel)).ToList();

     //3.Retrieve users
     var users = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Web.SiteUsers.Where(u => u.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User ));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     //4.Retrieve users permissions
     var userPermissionsResults = users.ToDictionary(user => user, user => ctx.Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions(user.LoginName));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     //5.Filter users by role
     var editorUsers = new List<User>();
     foreach (var result in userPermissionsResults)
     {
         var user = result.Key;
         var userPermissions = result.Value.Value;
         var hasPermissions = permissionLevels.All(userPermissions.Has); //has the same permissions?
         if (hasPermissions)
         {
             editorUsers.Add(user);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for the reply. Yes, I tried the first method and it works very well. I am facing a little issue. I am not sure it has anything to do with this. After getting the user from result.key object, when i try to add thi user to a field in a sharepoint column, it changes the value of that user. I mean, if i add user1, it adds user2 instead. Any ideas on this unexpected behavior. I also tried loading the user again using EnuserUser() method. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Good to know, regarding the issue, i will try to reproduce it and get back to you..

Comment: To update on the issue, when i am getting the user using result.key method, it is not returning the correct id of the user. It is returning a different user id. is that possible? what is the scope of the user id? is it unique at site collection level or at farm level?

Comment: regarding user id, I believe the scope of user id is site collection