# Get Sharepoint Permissions\Roles (custom) of a user from AD Group that is part of SP Group via CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, security, provider-hosted-app, ad

SharePoint 2013 + provider-hosted app.

User is part of AD group.
AD group is part of Sharepoint group.
Sharepoint group has custom security permissions assigned.

How do I check whether user has some custom permission?

The only way I could think of is to get user AD groups and retrieve permissions for these groups from SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx) an option? You should be able to get permission information via the RoleDefinition and RoleAssignment endpoints.

Also see this [Stack Exchange answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128055/get-all-users-based-on-a-specific-permission-role-in-net-csom-in-sharepoint-201?rq=1) which uses [Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getusereffectivepermissions(v=office.15).aspx)